# Can't receive email with msmtp using google account

Tags: configuration, gmail, msmtp

I'm experiencing issue with msmtp on my backup server (OpenSUSE 12.2). I'm trying to send email everytime some of my backups fail. For this reason I would like to use msmtp. I have everything setted up. However, even though I see sent items in my "Sent" AND "Inbox" folder in Gmail, I never received single email on my desired Email account. Could anyone help me please? Scripts follow bellow. Please see that recipient is my gmail acc in log even though in text.txt is different.

**.msmtprc**

```
account default
host smtp.gmail.com
port 587
protocol smtp
from myemail@gmail.com
tls on
tls_starttls on
#tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
tls_certcheck off
tls_nocertcheck
auth on
user myemail@gmail.com
password Mypassword
logfile ~/.msmtp
```

**.msmtp**

```
Feb 25 09:44:28 host=smtp.gmail.com tls=on auth=on user=myemail@gmail.com
from=myemail@gmail.com recipients=myemail@gmail.com mailsize=130 smtpstatus=250 
smtpmsg='250 2.0.0 OK 1393317868 g1sm73904348eet.6 - gsmtp' exitcode=EX_OK
```

**text.txt**

```
From: Daily backups <myemail@gmail.com>
To: Recipient's Name <hisemail@domain.com>
Subject: Backup report
Sample text
```

**Command for send email**

```
$ cat text.txt | msmtp -a default myemail@gmail.com
```

Big thank to all of those who will try to help me.
David

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me....

```
account default
host smtp.gmail.com
port 587
logfile /tmp/msmtp.log
tls on
tls_starttls on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

auth login
user myemail@gmail.com
password MyPassWord1
from First LastName

account account2
```

And then from raspberry Pi command line

```
echo -e "Subject: Test Mail\r\n\r\nThis is a test mail" |msmtp --debug --from=default -t destinationaddress@gmail.com
```

Comment: Worked well in 2020

Comment: It still works and works well with PHP 7.3 as well. If you get "TLS Handshake error", make sure "tls_starttls" is on.